# How to send a merge request for a new unit test that fails?

Tags: github, etiquette

I found a bug in a open source project.  The bug is easy to reproduce and as such I have added a failing unit test (the project already uses unit tests) and submitted a pull request.

I have not fixed the problem, I just wrote a unit test illustrating the problem.

The PR cannot be merged because the unit test fails.  Did I do the right thing by submitting the unit tests as a PR?  Should I have done something different?

Comment: @Abigail Honestly, that looks like the basis for a good answer! I didn't know about the practice of separate TODO tests. A brief description of project-management options would be really useful. You (or anyone else who cares to answer) could even approach it from the other side and consider "If you *operate* a project, should (and how could) you accept deliberately failing unit tests?" as part of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the programming language you are using you can creatge a mergerequest with a disabled/ignored unittest.

This avoid having  [failing-unit-tests](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58248/what-is-the-value-of-checking-in-failing-unit-tests/58509#58509) in the code branch which can be easyly reenabled when fixing the issue.